# Equation : $2\sqrt{x}x^{2}-\sin x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Solve :

$2\sqrt{x}x^{2}-\sin x=0$

Where $0≤x<\frac{π}{2}$

$x=0$ its clearly root

I think $2\sqrt{x}x^{2}-\sin x>0$ because $\sin x≤x$

I'm correct or no ?

Comment: Would a numerical (aproximate) answer be OK?

Comment: Sir , sée now im correct ?

Comment: It's an easy calculus exercise to show that $2\sqrt x x^2-\sin x$ is *decreasing* at $x=0$, and from there to show that it has another root in the interval $(0,1)$. Are you looking for a *pre*-calculus solution? (In any event, I think the other root can only be evaluated numerically.)

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not correct. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E2*sqrt(x)-sin(x)%3D0).

Comment: google newton raphson method

Comment: Put $f(x)=2x^2\sqrt x$ and $g(x)=\sin x$. Do you have
$$f(0.60457)\approx0.5683900\\g(0.60457)\approx0.5684083$$ 
What does this suggest?

Answer (score 1):

To get a "good" starting point, use Taylor expansion to get
$$2 x^{5/2}-\sin (x)=-x+2 x^{5/2}+O\left(x^{3}\right)$$ So, beside the trivial root $x=0$, you have an *estimate*
$$x=\frac{1}{2^{2/3}}\approx 0.629961$$ Now, Newton iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.6299605249 \\
 1 & 0.6058181550 \\
 2 & 0.6045851549 \\
 3 & 0.6045819682 \\
 4 & 0.6045819681
\end{array}
\right)$$